# AWS Marketplace search/query API

Tags: amazon-web-services, marketplace

I need programmatic access to the AWS marketplace UI functionality. So far i found the "AmazonEC2.describeImages" API but I find it very limiting:

1) Results do not match what I get in UI. As an example simple query for Tomcat AMIs:

```
Filter isPublic = new Filter().withName("is-public").withValues("true");
Filter tomcat = new Filter().withName("name").withValues("Tomcat*");
DescribeImagesRequest req = new DescribeImagesRequest().withFilters( isPublic, tomcat );
DescribeImagesResult resp = ec2.describeImages( req );
```

Result:

```
Found total 9 images
ID: ami-542eae43
Name:   Tomcat7_v01
Desc:   [Copied ami-00369873 from eu-west-1] Tomcat7_v01
Arch:   x86_64
Type:   machine
Owner:  616727669948
    Device name:    /dev/sda1  (size: 10)
ID: ami-5b1b7a4c
Name:   TomcatInstance
Desc:   TomcatInstance
Arch:   x86_64
Type:   machine
Owner:  312088435046
    Device name:    /dev/sda1  (size: 10)
ID: ami-61137676
Name:   Tomcat 9 on windows powered by GlobalSolutions-1ba56c23-b93c-4f5d-b31b-159b21b7b943-ami-1dc75d0a.3
Desc:   Tomcat 9 on windows powered by GlobalSolutions
Arch:   x86_64
Platform:   windows
Type:   machine
Owner:  679593333241
    Device name:    /dev/sda1  (size: 30)
ID: ami-7153e20b
Name:   Tomcat 9-472baf5a-498f-41a9-8f1d-861fe627200c-ami-b45bf1ce.4
Desc:   Updated debian.cnf
Arch:   x86_64
Type:   machine
Owner:  679593333241
    Device name:    /dev/sda1  (size: 8)
ID: ami-8c4d81e4
Name:   TomcatPGSQLWorking
Desc:   [Copied ami-19552c29 from us-west-2] TomcatPGSQLWorking
Arch:   x86_64
Type:   machine
Owner:  525242879332
    Device name:    /dev/sda1  (size: 8)
ID: ami-95da17fc
Name:   Tomcat7
Desc:   Tomcat 7 Image
Arch:   x86_64
Type:   machine
Owner:  209720127264
    Device name:    /dev/sda1  (size: 8)
ID: ami-a9b9d1c0
Name:   Tomcat_06
Desc:   
Arch:   x86_64
Type:   machine
Owner:  550038334991
    Device name:    /dev/sda1  (size: 8)
    Device name:    /dev/sdb
ID: ami-b2c9a6da
Name:   Tomcat Designer and Search Image (with genomes)
Desc:   [Copied ami-236f7266 from us-west-1] Tomcat Designer and Search Image (with genomes)
Arch:   x86_64
Type:   machine
Owner:  872553423352
    Device name:    /dev/xvda  (size: 200)
ID: ami-b9bbc5ae
Name:   Tomcat8.5.5.-PotgreSQL9.5-Server
Desc:   
Arch:   x86_64
Type:   machine
Owner:  541102566093
    Device name:    /dev/xvda  (size: 20)
```

When I perform that search in UI I get 28 hits. Clearly I don't know the specific filter combination that UI is using, so I used a very simple combo.

2) Name and Description are lacking

Look at the result above. Names are not too bad, bur descriptions are often useless. Some are fine like "Tomcat 7 image", other times it is blank or just a company URL. Descriptions are all over the place.

3) Supported instance types

In marketplace UI I can look at an AMI and see a table of supported instance types where the AMI can be deployed. However in the desribeImages result I don't see that information. How can I access the list of applicable instance types.

In summary,

Is there another API that can give me more information on a specific AMI, something like:

desribeImageDetails(String imageId)

That would give me full details?

thanks